# iOS10 - Implement SiriKit Messaging API to send messages via Webservice calls

Tags: ios, ios10, siri, sirikit

I am trying to implement Siri for chatting or messaging App. and messages will be sent via APIs, How can i wait for the response of web-service and then respond to user via Siri that message has been sent.

I tried to call a webservice, but before getting response Siri is saying "Open APP_NAME".  how can we send SMS

And is it possible to read extra parameters in Messaging voice command?

e.g In voice command to send message, User will also mention the Car Number, 1 hour or 2 hours time,  and we will format the message with specific criteria, and SMS will be sent to a fixed number to book Parking Slot for Car for 1 hour.

e.g:  Send message with APP_NAME to book parking for Car number "A12345 for  1 hour"

We will fetch Car Number, Time Slot, and send a comma separated message to a constant mobile number via SMS

Any suggest if it is feasible by SiriKit in iOS10? and is there any risk Apple will reject this app for above implementation via Messaging Intents?

Comment: Have you read https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Intents/Conceptual/SiriIntegrationGuide/ ?

Comment: @rocky, yes i have read the documentation and after reading it i asked the question as it was not clear in documentation.